# ExpectedException extract the ExceptionType to a System.Type variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

Following approach works,

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ApiException), StaticStringHelper.ApiDoesNotSupportThisMethod)]
    public async Task CreditCard_GetAll_MethodNotAllowed()
    {
        //Test

    }
```

`StaticStringHelper.ApiDoesNotSupportThisMethod` is a string variable.
I want to extract the ExceptionType to a variable so that it can be reused across all unit tests. Reason is that if I introduce a custom exception for method not allowed in future instead of the generic exception, I only have to change one place.

```
    private static Type typeVariable = Type.GetType("ApiException");

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeVariable, StaticStringHelper.ApiDoesNotSupportThisMethod)]
    public async Task CreditCard_GetAll_MethodNotAllowed()
    {

    }
```

This does not work.

[image]

According to the [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) it accepts "System.Type" as the first parameter.

Is there a way to get around?

Comment: did u mean private const Type type = typeof(ApiException); ? you can't do this